# netty-socketio established connection domain name path exception

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, socketserver, netty-socketio

Client Connection Information：

`var socket =  io('ws://abc.com/customRequestPath', { query: { 'clientUserCode': 'my-value'//类似于上面的写法 }, reconnection: true, reconnectionDelay: 1000, reconnectionDelayMax: 5000, reconnectionAttempts: 50, transports: ['websocket'] });`

The path for the browser to establish a socket link:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtpP4.jpg)

The browser establishes the socket link path is ws://abc.com/socket.io/，And the request path I expect should be ws://abc.com/customRequestPath/socket.io/。

Is this a bug?Please give me some advice.

The browser establishes the socket link path is ws://abc.com/socket.io/，And the request path I expect should be ws://abc.com/customRequestPath/socket.io/。